# how to wire up LIS302DLH with arduino? (or similar, small accelerometer)

Tags: arduino, accelerometer

heads up: I'm new to electronics and have just started working with the arduino.

I'm trying to hook up a `LIS302DLH` accelerometer ([spec sheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/389/CD00237146-64752.pdf)) with the arduino. I've successfully managed to get the `adxl335` (e.g. [link](http://bildr.org/2011/04/sensing-orientation-with-the-adxl335-arduino/)) to work but the `adxl335` is too big for my application. That's why I was looking into the `LIS302DLH`. Unfortunately, I don't know how to hook it up.

Therefore my question: how to I hook up the `LIS302DLH` with the arduino? Do alternative small accelerometers exist that might do the job?

**EDIT** what want to know is how to connect (wire up) the `LIS302DLH` with the arduino. which pin needs to be connected to what?

Comment: Can you be more precise? What exactly is the problem? Is it mechanical connection between accelerometer and Arduino, placement or accelerometer itself, is it the correct pinout or some problem with logic level translation?

Comment: @AndrejaKo I need to know how to build the circuit (ie connect what pin to what) to make the arduino read out the chip correctly. I've added an edit to my post.

Comment: If you take a look at [datasheet](http://www.kosmodrom.com.ua/pdf/LIS302DLH.pdf) page 8. basically, everything is explained. You can choose between SPI or I2C and depend on that use wires that corresponds to the protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** The specified accelerometer operates up to 3.6 Volts, so it will require level translation to work with one of the classic (5 Volts) Arduinos. If the Arduino you are using is one of the newer 3.3 Volt boards, then this level translation is not required.

For level translation information, you will find many related questions in this site, so this answer does not cover it.

For pin to pin connecting up, using SPI mode:

- Sensor pin 07 to Arduino SS Slave pin (slave select, drive low to communicate)
- Sensor pin 12 to Arduino MISO pin
- Sensor pin 13 to Arduino MOSI pin
- Sensor pin 14 to Arduino SCK pin
- Sensor pin 08 to any free Arduino interrupt enabled pin, use digital pin 2
- Sensor pin 09 to any other Arduino interrupt enabled pin, use digital pin 3

The MISO/MISO/SCK/SS default pins for various Arduino boards, from the [Arduino SPI reference](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI), are given below:

[image: SPI pins]

Some of the SPI pins are available on the ICSP header on all Arduino boards, for consistency:

[image: ICSP Header]

For the SS and interrupt pins, any free digital IO pins on the Arduino may be used, no specific standards need to be followed.

---

The I2C method of connection is best avoided for this part, as the I2C bus speed limitation will give marginal results.